# Any meaning to versions of tags; what to do about an overzealous tag-editor

Tags: discussion, tags

I asked two question on the Play Framework.

[Good, idiomatic way to refactor out business logic from controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230896/good-idiomatic-way-to-refactor-out-business-logic-from-controllers) and 
[JSON parsing with Play: why is a list being parsed this way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165337/json-parsing-with-play-why-is-a-list-being-parsed-this-way)

I noticed that one user has edited the questions to "Added playframework-2.0 and scala tags" on one question and with "playframework-2.1" on the other. Reviewers actually approved this blindly. I actually use 2.0.3 and believe my question is applicable to many past and future releases.

Is there a general guideline to which tag to choose: one spanning across major versions (1.x and 2.x currently), for specific major versions and down to minor versions? Is it okay to overlook actions like his?

Background: The Play Framework allows both Java and Scala code and current production versions are 1.2.* and 2.*. Java and Scala syntaxes are distinct.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, the version-specific tags should be used for cases when that specific version is important to understanding/answering the question. They should not be used to just pepper a question with more, seemingly-related tags. And certainly, tags for *different* versions than the asker is using are not valid.